# Syntax for random forest using xgboost in python

Tags: python, xgboost

In the intro of xgboost (R release) one may  construct a random forest like classifier using the below shown commands. Is it possible to do the same with xgboost in python?

```
#Random Forest™ - 1000 trees
bst <- xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, max_depth = 4, num_parallel_tree = 1000, subsample = 0.5, colsample_bytree =0.5, nrounds = 1, objective = "binary:logistic")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are able to use the same parameters in python. You can find several python examples on how to use xgboost in the demo directory:

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/guide-python

Simply supply the parameters from your R command in python and it should work the same.

Comment: The problem is that num_parallel_tree and nrounds parameters do not exist in the python documentation for xgboost, any thoughts?

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. Well nrounds I think is called num_boost_round in the python api. And num_parellel_tree does exist in the python api even though it is not explicitly document. To see this search for num_boost_round in the training file: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/training.py

Comment: I also found a python file that uses the num_parallel_tree parameter. See https://programtalk.com/vs2/python/6841/ensemble_amazon/XGBoostClassifier.py/ Note: They use a self defined parameter called num_round and pass it on to what is called num_boost_round in the python api.